# How to create a 10MB file filled with "000000..." data in golang?

Tags: file, go, fsync, sparse-file

I am intended to use fdatasync in a system like log or diskqueue.
The first thing is to create a 10MB file with "000000..." in file system like ext4.
But I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp/SO/16797380$ ls -l
celkem 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jnml jnml 186 kvě 29 07:54 main.go
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp/SO/16797380$ cat main.go 
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        f, err := os.Create("foo.bar")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := f.Truncate(1e7); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp/SO/16797380$ go run main.go 
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp/SO/16797380$ ls -l
celkem 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jnml jnml 10000000 kvě 29 07:55 foo.bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jnml jnml      186 kvě 29 07:54 main.go
jnml@fsc-r630:~/src/tmp/SO/16797380$
```

Comment: I actually prefer this method to the one I provided as I think the use of `Truncate` is quite clean and elegant.

Comment: I love this one. It is elegant. But it's still a sparse file. I don't sure this is the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using unix, then you can create a sparse file very quickly.  A sparse file is filled with zero (ascii NUL) and doesn't actually take up the disk space until it is written to, but reads correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    size := int64(10 * 1024 * 1024)
    fd, err := os.Create("output")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to create output")
    }
    _, err = fd.Seek(size-1, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to seek")
    }
    _, err = fd.Write([]byte{0})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Write failed")
    }
    err = fd.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to close file")
    }
}
```

Which produces a 10MB file called `output`.

```
$ ls -l output 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 10485760 May 28 18:58 output
$ du -hs output 
4.0K    output
```

**Update** much later

I solved exactly this problem in rclone.  Namely preallocating files without writing the data, or creating a sparse file.  You can't do it directly from the standard library and it isn't cross platform, but using the [fallocate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) syscall with the `FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE` flag is the way to go in linux.  You can also do this in windows.

Here are links to the relevant code in [windows](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/blob/18c029e0f0c3a5dd0c925e285ce39071cb8728ff/backend/local/preallocate_windows.go) and [linux](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/blob/18c029e0f0c3a5dd0c925e285ce39071cb8728ff/backend/local/preallocate_unix.go) and here is the linux code:

```golang
var (
    fallocFlags = [...]uint32{
        unix.FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE,                             // Default
        unix.FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE | unix.FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE, // for ZFS #3066
    }
    fallocFlagsIndex int32
)

// preAllocate the file for performance reasons
func preAllocate(size int64, out *os.File) error {
    if size <= 0 {
        return nil
    }
    index := atomic.LoadInt32(&fallocFlagsIndex)
again:
    if index >= int32(len(fallocFlags)) {
        return nil // Fallocate is disabled
    }
    flags := fallocFlags[index]
    err := unix.Fallocate(int(out.Fd()), flags, 0, size)
    if err == unix.ENOTSUP {
        // Try the next flags combination
        index++
        atomic.StoreInt32(&fallocFlagsIndex, index)
        fs.Debugf(nil, "preAllocate: got error on fallocate, trying combination %d/%d: %v", index, len(fallocFlags), err)
        goto again

    }
    // FIXME could be doing something here
    // if err == unix.ENOSPC {
    //  log.Printf("No space")
    // }
    return err
}
```

Comment: A sparse file doesn't satisfy my requirement. I wanna use fdatasync rather than fsync, so the metadata of the file should not be changed in later wirte-operations.

Comment: From my reading of the man page I think fdatasync will work fine on sparse files. None of the metadata needs to be updated when you write to a sparse file.

Comment: Would you please give me some url-links? I still got confusing.

Comment: Relevant man pages [fdatasync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fdatasync) and [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). Writing to the sparse sections of the file could change **blkcnt_t** so maybe it will update the metadata.  Anyway, if you are after ultimate performance then don't write a sparse file as there is more overhead when writing to it.  If you want to create a 1 GB backing file instantly then do use a sparse file!

Comment: That's exactly what I worry about. But now, I have to give up this sync-thing, just let os auto-flush by itself. In mostly situation, it seems safty enough. And it also have good peformance compare to sync.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
package foo

import "io"

func WriteBytes(w io.Writer, c byte, n uint) {
    buf := make([]byte,0x1000)

    for i := 0 ; i < len(buf) ; i++ {
        buf[i] = c
    }

    for i := 0 ; i < n >> 24 ; i++ {
        w.Write(buf)
    }

    w.Write(buf[:n & 0xfff])
}
```

Comment: This could make a sparse file too. I'm not sure about it. So if I must choose an answer, I like the `Truncate` best.

Comment: @hardPass This is very unlikely to create a sparse file.  Ideally, you'd use the `syscall.Fallocate()` function for this on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

This will create a 10000000 byte file in the current directory named `testfile`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    data := make([]byte, int(1e7), int(1e7)) // Initialize an empty byte slice
    f, err := os.Create("testfile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    size, err := f.Write(data) // Write it to the file
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes written", size)
}
```

Hope that helps.